# div or table layout without clear row or column structure

Tags: css, html, layout

I try to construct the following structure by using div-containers (form with information). I just don't get it. There is no clear column or row system. Any ideas?

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
+       +       b       +
+   a   +++++++++++++++++
+       +   c   +       +
+++++++++++++++++   d   +
+       e       +       +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I should have mentioned, that a and d are fixed in width (a left aligned, d right aligned) and b,c,e (which are all left aligned) should vary in width with content.

Comment: Best to add your html and css

Comment: Absolute positioning looks like the best solution here, especially since your divs clearly need to have both height and width fixed anyway.

Comment: You really don't want to see this...

Comment: If you need to do this with variable-width containers, [a table-based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16486159/901048) is going to be best.

Comment: Looks like you're wanting something like the Masonry library (JavaScript).

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous.  Look at the range of responses!  With HTML+CSS, the answer to *how* is usually very closely related to *why*.  Are you trying to create a decorative pinwheel shape with just CSS?  Does `a` represent website navigation, `b` a header, `c` content, `d` a sidebar, and `e` a footer?  Are `c` and `e` *both* content?  There's more than one way to do it.  There's even more than one *right* way to do it.  But there are plenty of *wrong* ways to do it as well that can just cause headaches down the road.  Avoid headaches by clarifying what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Thank you all. I went with Blazemongers "absolute"-version. It fits my purpose quite well and is very simple. Buuuuut: There is another question: I have to center an image vertically in a and c and align a form at the bottom of e. At the moment I defined another div within e.g. a and used "display: table-cell" as well as "vertical-align: middle". Is this a good way to do it? Any problems? Smarter solutions?

Comment: If you just want to vertically center an image within an absolutely-positioned fixed-size element, you might as well absolutely position it, too. Otherwise, use the full-table approach and you won't even need your hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to position everything absolutely:

```
#a,#b,#c,#d,#e {
    position: absolute;
}
#a {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#b {
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
#c {
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
#d {
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
}
#e {
    left: 0;
    top: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gyxJJ/1/

Comment: @Michael Not easily, but if you have an example, by all means, share it.

Comment: @Blazemonger You can see example with floats in my answer)

Comment: @FAngel Since you have to use a wrapper to keep the floats in place, and all the elements have fixed dimensions, I don't see your solution as having any advantages over mine.

Comment: absolute positioning would constrain width AND height to precise values. One more line of content and content will superimpose (like fonts a little bit bolder on OS X and linux distribs or simply more content than expected initially, not speaking of text zoom needed by some people to perceive web content)

Comment: Thank you Blazemonger - I took your method. It is clear and simple and even I can understand it. I got another (minor?) problem about aligning - described in the comments above. Maybe another good hint? Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `rowspan` and `colspan` properties of `td`.

**Example:**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">a</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td rowspan="2">d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">e</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYDBa/)

Comment: (responding to a deleted comment from Blazemonger) It could still be the only manageable solution. Really, even in 2013 with table used for layout legitimately despised. **If** you need not to constrain widths of your "columns" for example and have same height cells, well colspan and rowspan do NOT have equivalent in CSS and won't have for the near future. Except grid layout but it's IE10 only

Comment: Yes, a table could be used to get the desired layout, but it won't reflow gracefully if it must be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T9Vvg/ You may use something like that.

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
.a {
    height:98px;
    width:48px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
.b {
    height:48px;
    width:98px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
.c {
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
.d {
    height:98px;
    width:48px;
    float:right;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
.e {
    height:48px;
    width:98px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class=wrapper>
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
    <div class="d">d</div>
    <div class="e">e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you sooo much. a and d will be fixed size. Is there a possibility that b c and e will be of variable width?

Comment: I hardly imagine how it may work. need to think on it. But my advice - take a look at solution based on tables. That will be much easier to build structure like that with variable widths/heights

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tPJAQ/

Heres a semi-sort-of-kinda responsive version based on the above.

Comment: @Michael yeah. I was thinking about that. But it is almost the same as with width/height in pixels. It will not change dimensions based on inner content. Only benefit here is that you can increase general width/height of a block in one turn.

Comment: @FAngel indeed.  With a little javascript I suppose it could be made better.  Or better yet, flexbox.

Comment: @Michael Flexbox won't be of any use for this layout because there's no concept of spanning.  The elements must flow as either rows or columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starter: http://jsfiddle.net/asxde/

You may or may not need to have some elements fixed width, depends on your precise design and constraints. A and D in particular.

CSS:

```
div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 40px;
}
.a {
    float: left;
    min-height: 80px;
}
.b {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.c {
    float: left;
}
.d {
    float: right;
    min-height: 80px;
}
.e {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="a">aaa</div>
<div class="b">bbb</div>
<div class="c">ccc</div>
<div class="d">ddd</div>
<div class="e">eee</div>
```

Comment: I don't think your fiddle works as well as you think it does.

Comment: That's why it's a starter. One must know if A and D are fixed widths or not, or other constraints.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention: A and D will be fixed width. Updated the question...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tPJAQ/

Here is a method forked from FAngel's answer above.

```
.wrapper{
    height:/*250px*/ 100%;
    width:/*250px*/ 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    border:solid 1px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.a {
    height:66.666666%;
    width:33.333333%;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b {
    height:33.333333%;
    width:66.666666%;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.c {
    height:33.333333%;
    width:33.333333%;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.d {
    height:66.666666%;
    width:33.333333%;
    float:right;
    border:solid 1px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.e {
    height:33.333333%;
    width:66.666666%;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `min-height` and `max-height` equal to `height`?

Comment: Honestly I was trying something else and forgot to remove it. haha